# Performance issues when replicating tables with Kafka Connect & Debezium to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm experiencing performance issues when replicating tables using Debezium and Kafka Connect.

The slow replication is only experienced during the initial snapshot of the database. One table that I tested with, contains 3.4m rows and the replication took 2 hours to complete.

At this stage, the entire database was locked and I was unable to commit data to other tables that were not being synced at the time.

My configuration (Debezium config deployed via curl request):

```
{
  "name": "debezium-connector",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",  
    "database.hostname": "redacted",  
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "redacted",
    "database.password": "redacted",
    "database.server.id": "54005",
    "database.server.name": "redacted", 
    "database.include.list": "redacted",
    "table.include.list": "redacted",
    "database.history.consumer.security.protocol":"SSL",
    "database.history.producer.security.protocol":"SSL",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "redacted",  
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.debezium-test",
    "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
    "max.queue.size": 81290,
    "max.batch.size": 20480
  }
}
```

Kafka Connect configuration that was changed:

```
CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_TIMEOUT_MS: 60000
```

Questions:
1 - How can I improve performance during the initial snapshot of the database?
2 - How can I replicate a limited number of tables from a database, without locking the entire database?

Answer (score 1):

if you can make sure that database schema will not change during snapshot process then you can avoid locking the database via https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-snapshot-locking-mode

Also check https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-min-row-count-to-stream-results option, there might be also some performance change using it properly.

You can also `max.batch.size` together with `max.queue.size` even more than you have it right now.

Comment: The `snapshot.locking.mode` parameter was altered to `none`. I will alter the `max.batch.size` and `max.queue.size` parameters and increase the sizes thereof. Thank you Jiri.

Comment: Any review on your settings? Did it prevent from locking to long?